# How Can I Write a Test for a Javascript Asynchronous method like below usning jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Please, I would appreciate if I can get a help out here to find a suitable test for the function below. It works perfectly fine in my project but I just cannot figure out why my test won't work. Thank you guys...

```
const GetScore = (() => {
  const all = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('https://us-central1-js-capstone-backend.cloudfunctions.net/api/games/ZUi2Xo2RRfSKd14twwPn/scores/', {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });
    const data = await response.json();
    return data;
  };
  return {
    all,
  };
})();

module.exports = GetScore;
```

My test is as follows

```
const GetScore = require('../modules/getScore');

let results = false;

it('returns an array of objects with all the scores', () => {
  GetScore.all().then((response) => {
    if (Array.isArray(response.result) === true) results = true;
    expect(results).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

The error I get is like this:

```
node:internal/process/promises:246
          triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
          ^

[UnhandledPromiseRejection: This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason "ReferenceError: fetch is not defined".] {
  code: 'ERR_UNHANDLED_REJECTION'
```

Thank you guys in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test is not asynchronous so it is not waiting for the call to finish.  Add an async/await in your test.

```
it('returns an array of objects with all the scores', async () => {
    await GetScore.all().then((response) => {
        if (Array.isArray(response.result) === true) results = true;
        expect(results).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

You should also write tests for the failures, so you might want to wrap the await in a try/catch.

Comment: Thank you Steven, for your answer. It worked exactly as you suggested.